# font-family in FOP

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I was just wondering, is it possible, to name several alternative fonts in an FO-File? 
I know it's possible in HTML and CSS, but I couldn't find anything about XSL-FO.

Like this:

```
h1 {
  font-family: arial, verdana, serif;
}
```

My problem is, that FOP can't use most of my fonts, so it would be great if I could find a possibility to give FOP like 3 font-names and it then tries to use all of them, before using Times New Roman.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, I finally had the chance to try it and yes, it works just as Mads Hansen said, so thank you. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It works like CSS** ([although with FOP, it may not behave exactly the same](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-font-selection-strategy)).  [XSL-FO’s font-family property is specified as a list of font names, separated by commas, in order from first choice to last choice](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#font-family).

> This property specifies a prioritized
>   list of font family names and/or
>   generic family names. To deal with the
>   problem that a single font may not
>   contain glyphs to display all the
>   characters in a document, or that not
>   all fonts are available on all
>   systems, this property allows authors
>   to specify a list of fonts, all of the
>   same style and size, that are tried in
>   sequence to see if they contain a
>   glyph for a certain character. This
>   list is called a font set.

**FOP can be configured in a number of ways to load additional fonts.**  The easiest is to [set the **auto-detect** flag, and FOP will scan your system for installed fonts](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/fonts.html#autodetect).

> When the "auto-detect" flag is set in
>   the configuration, FOP will
>   automatically search for fonts in the
>   default paths for your operating
>   system.
>
> FOP will also auto-detect fonts which
>   are available in the classpath, if
>   they are described as
>   "application/x-font" in the
>   MANIFEST.MF file. For example, if your
>   .jar file contains font/myfont.ttf:
>
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> ```
>       Name: font/myfont.ttf
>       Content-Type: application/x-font
> ```
>
> This feature allows you to create JAR
>   files containing fonts. The JAR files
>   can be added to fop by providem them
>   in the classpath, e.g. copying them
>   into the lib/ directory.

Comment: There is a problem with FOP and "it works just like CSS". [FOP does not support](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-font-selection-strategy) the FO property [font-selection-strategy](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#font-selection-strategy).

Comment: Fair enough. Not *exactly* like CSS.

Comment: I would say that it is supposed to work exactly like CSS. But it won't work for @Isthatpossible, who is using FOP.

Comment: OK, if @Isthatpossible says that it works, then I suppose I was wrong. Apparently a "word-by-word" strategy is implemented: http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/FontSelectionStrategy.